# ¿Por qué se usa el asterisco en import java.util.* y qué utilidades tiene?

Tags: java

Estaba leyendo un libro sobre hacer el código más limpio y legible.

El caso es que, mirando un código del libro, aparecía un paquete de Java que terminaba por asterisco y lo escribían de esta manera `import java.util.*`. Siempre en los paquetes `import java.util` he visto acabados en `arraylist`, `scanner` o `date`.

Mis dudas son ¿qué indica o significa el asterisco? y ¿qué utilidad tiene?

Comment: Buenas y bienvenido, si no me equivoco en java que un paquete termine en asterisco es debido a que de esta manera se importa todo el contenido. Vamos que importarias todo, desde los ejemplos que has puesto de arraylist y scanner. La utilidad la verdad solo pienso que seria por comodidad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El asterisco en los imports de Java tiene dos funcionalidades, aunque se pueden resumir en una: Hacer visibles todos los miembros de una colección sin tener que usar su nombre (identificador) completo.

### 1. Importar de un paquete:

Es el ejemplo que has puesto. Si tienes que hacer una *aplicación pequeña* que hace uso de distintas colecciones (Set, Map, List) y/o de otras clases o interfaces de uso común y no estás usando un IDE para crearla, es my cómodo escribir:

```
import java.util.*;
```

en lugar del tedioso listado:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
...
```

Si estás usando un IDE como Eclipse, IntelliJ o Netbeans, te recomiendo escribir el nombre de la clase cuando vayas a usarla, pulsar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>espacio</kbd> y dejar que el autocompletado haga su magia, incluyendo automáticamente el import necesario de cada clase. De este modo evitarás conflictos innecesarios. Por ejemplo si tienes:

```
import java.util.*
import java.sql.*;
```

Te encontrarás que ¡hay dos clases Date importadas a la vez!

### 2. Importar de una clase:

Hay un segundo tipo de import en Java, el *estático*, en cuyo caso lo que importas son los métodos y atributos estáticos de una clase:

```
import static java.lang.System.out; //sólo un atributo
import static java.lang.Math.*; //todos los métodos!

class Demo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      //En lugar de Math.sqrt
      double var1= sqrt(5.0);
      //En lugar de Math.tan 
      double var2= tan(30);
      //En lugar de System.out.println
      out.println("La raíz de 5 es:"+var1);
      out.println("Tangente de 30 es:"+var2);
   }

}
```

En este caso es más improbable el encontrarse conflictos, porque no solemos importar más de una o dos clases estáticas dentro de una misma clase.

Comment: No sabia sobre los estaticos, me ha parecido buenisima explicacion!! Gracias

Comment: ¿Sobre los estáticos no existiría un problema parecido en caso de que se use dos clases parecidas?

Comment: Sí, mira el último párrafo

Comment: A eso me referia, se me ha debido pasar, muy bien explicado.

Answer (score 6):

Con

```
import java.util.*;
```

Importas todas las clases que dependen de `java.util`. Mientras que si haces refrencia solo a una, solo se importará esa en particular. Por ejemplo

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Siempre es mejor realizar un `import` de las clases que necesites. De otra forma en ocasiones podemos encontrarnos con conflictos de nombres innecesarios. El rendimiento solo se ve afectado (mínimamente) en la compilación, no tiene ningún efecto negativo en la ejecución.

Comment: Una lista exhaustiva de todas las clases e interfaces englobadas en el paquete `java.util` para el JDK 8 se puede encontrar aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html

Comment: Y que utilidad puedo sacar de usar el asterisco? Quiero decir si voy a usar la clase date y scanner me conviene usarlo o deberia importarlo por individual?

Comment: Siempre es mejor realizar un `import` de las clases que necesites. De otra forma en ocasiones puedes encontrar conflictos de nombres innecesarios.

Comment: A nivel de recursos imagino que será más recomendable importar sólo las clases específicas que vas a usar en lugar de importarlas todas. No tendría sentido meterle al proyecto clases que no vas a usar. Sería como hacer un import java.*

Comment: El rendimiento solo se ve afectado (mínimamente) en la compilación, no tiene ningún efecto negativo en la ejecución. Pero siempre es mejor ser pulcro con el código.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias, al menos se me quita la duda y puedo mirarlo en detalle.

Comment: Usar `import java.util*`no afecta el rendimiento en tiempo de compilación, esto se debe porqué en realidad no estás agregando todas las clases en un mismo archivo. El asterisco `*` es una simple indicación para el compilador, donde se le dice que se puede usar cualquier clase de un paquete.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando usas el asterisco al final de un `import`, importas todas las clases que tiene dentro, pero **no se aconseja** su uso debido a que puede darte problemas a la hora de programar o si quieres reutilizar el código debido a que te puede dar conflictos con otros `import`. Por ejemplo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

// ...

List decisiones = new List();
```

Debido a esto hay un conflicto ya que Java 1.2 añadieron util y contenía List al igual que awt. Cierto es que se puede "arreglar" ya que si pones otro import de util especificando List no debería dar de problemas pero eso ya es opinión de cada uno y en la mía tener que hacer import import.* para tener que luego especificar la clase pierde su punto.

En la compilación no te consumirá mucho siempre que no sea un gigantesco código y este lleno de imports con asteriscos.

Como has indicado que lo viste en un ejemplo probablemente lo pusieran para hacerlo mas legible. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Con problemas a cuales te refieres? Me gustaría saber en detalle para que me quede claro.

Comment: @LFMk.IXMH434 Imagínate que en una clase importas `java.util.*` Importando esto, estás implícitamente `java.util.Date`. Ahora imagínate que en esa clase quieres utilizar la clase `java.sql.Date`. Ahí tendrías que tener cuidado si haces `Date date = new Date();` ya que realmente estarías usando la versión de `java.util`. Si quisieras utilizar la otra versión tendrías que hacer `java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date();`

Comment: Hemos pensado todo el mundo en el ejemplo de Date por lo que veo xD

Comment: Todas las respuestas con ejemplos date, se ve que clase es la favorita del día. xD

Comment: Usar muchos `import` con asteriscos no consumirá mucho tiempo de compilación, ni por mas que tengas 10000 imports en tu codigo, esto se debe porqué en realidad no se está añadiendo todas clases en el archivo, ya que en Java no existe pre-compilación, tal como pasa en lenguajes como C/C++. El import ni si quiera será incluido en el código bytecode que genere el compilador de Java, debido a que es una simple indicación para el compilador.

Comment: Es decir, cuando tu haces esto: `import java util.*;` lo que le dice al compilador es lo siguiente: "Quiero tener acceso a todas las clases del paquete util". Entonces podrás usar cualquiera clase de dicho paquete sin problemas. En el caso contrario, cuando usas `import java.io.Scanner`, lo que se le dice al compilador en este caso es que solamente podrás usar la clase `Scanner` del paquete io. Así que por mas que importes sin asterisco o con asterisco, tendrán el mismo rendimiento en tiempo de compilación.

Answer (score 1):

Hay algo que no se ha mencionado en las respuestas anteriores y me parece importante: cuando utilizamos el * solo estamos importando las clases del paquete indicado, NO la de los posibles subpaquetes.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que queremos utilizar la clase Collectors que se encuentra en el paquete java.util.stream.

Lo siguiente no funciona ya que dicha clase se encuentra en el sub paquete stream.

```
import java.util.*;
```

Es necesario entonces navegar por la jerarquía de paquetes hasta llegar al nivel donde se encuentra la clase que se necesita.

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

o

```
import java.util.stream.*;
```

Después de incluir cualquiera de los dos import anteriores si tendremos visibilidad sobre la clase.